# PHP MySQL migration tool

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a migration tool that I'm supposed to use, but the old programmer never left any documentation on how to use it and we are unable to contact him.

This is the tool here:
https://github.com/davesloan/mysql-php-migrations

I have a MySQL database set up with Joomla for both locally and on the server. What I need to do is migrate the new MySQL local files to the server(We are using github for pushing and pulling.)

Anyone know how I can do so with this tool? I fiddled with the command line a bit but never got any results.

Thank you.

Comment: Upload the sql file to your server and do a command line mysql import: mysql -u user -p `database_name` < file.sql

Comment: Do you have deployment/build scripts set up when you push code to your repository?  If not, I would simply back up and restore the DB schema manually.  If you're not familiar with MySQL command line, look at a free solution like PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a different tool, where you have documentation, otherwise it's going to be tough deconstructing this.

I built a migrations tool that would work perfectly for what you need:

http://andrefigueira.github.io/Schematic/

It will map existing databases into the configuration files (schema files) and then can be used for future modifications, and these schema files are designed to be committed to your VCS and It's very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

You may try LazyRecord https://github.com/c9s/LazyRecord

LazyRecord integrates full featured PHP-based schema and the related migration features.

The most powerful feature is - automatic migration, which is similar to UIKit's lightweight database migration.

here are some screencasts:

[image]